# Substract Date from GETDATE() to get "time since"

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a elements that have values in DATETIME format in column 'Date Created'.

I would like to be able to extract value how long time ago it was from time at which query is executed (as a reference take GETDATE())

When executing this:

```
UPDATE #LPs
SET LastUsed = (GETDATE() - DateCreated)
```

I am getting 1900-01-01, I believe that is due to SQL Server limitations for minimal `DATETIME`.

How should I right is so I can get values like "2 years 3 months", "2 months" (any datetime format)?

Comment: You can easily use datediff to take the amount of days or months or years. But parse that time in a period and present it as a "human" readable text is a bit more complex. Also if you need it to be presented in a report or app UI you can move this logic complexity to the app. Let to the realtional DB just handle the relational logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, DateCreated, GETDATE()) 
FROM table
```

maybe it works

Comment: What data type should then column be? DATETIME?

Comment: Yes. I tried in my database and the result is in days(string). I hope it helps. :)

Comment: `CURDATE()` is a MySql function, but this is an Sql Server question. Sql server does not have a `CURDATE()` function, instead it has `GETDATE()`.

Comment: I managed to get it working with:
    'LastUsed INT
   UPDATE #LPs
    SET LastUsed = DATEDIFF(mm,DateCreated,GETDATE())'

It now shows number of months since.

Thanks!

Comment: @Gaberiel I didn't edit your answer, it was a user named jean, but hey, if anyone learned something from that then I'm not complaining...

Answer (score 3):

Sql server does not have a built in function that returns date differences as a formatted string like you want, but it does have a [`DATEDIFF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) function that will return the number of date parts between two dates:

```
DECLARE @Now datetime = GETDATE(),
        @Date datetime = GETDATE() + 5 -- five days from now

SELECT  @Now as Now,
        @Date as Date,
        DATEDIFF(Day, @Now, @Date) As DateDiff
```

You can get the number of months between the dates and calculate the string yourself using the [modulu operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279.aspx)